# pymol script to only select 5 chains within a distance from a reference and save the selection

Tags: protein-structure, visualization, pymol

I am generating 30 asymmetric units of a protein structure. Now, I want to select different combinations of 5 units which are 30 Angstroms away from the reference and save it as a different file. Here is the command I could work out till now :

```
fetch 3q2v
symexp sym,3q2v,(3q2v),30
select chains, bychain all within 30 of 3q2v
```

How to loop in and select only 5 chains at a time obtained from the setup obtained by the above code, and save it in separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would preface that the PyMOL command line in the GUI is great, but **you can run PyMOL as a regular Python library** (calling the appropriate python). This makes life so much simpler for more complex manipulations. You can do really complex manipulations with it. I cannot suggest it enough.
The API version of the commands works only marginally differently, but you can do API calls in the GUI `cmd.`) and PyMOLWiki documentation is only slightly weaker for them (`help()` fills the gaps).

But if you really want to use the GUI route...

Let's get the names of the models in the selection

```
onames = cmd.get_object_list('chains')
print onames
```

Now, you want to save subsets of 5 chains (technically, objects or models). That is, you do not care about the order they are in and you don't want the same one twice (actually selections with 4 or less), so you want all combinations. Make sure to do the following
    print len(onames)

And google that number as `<n> choose 5`. That is how many files you will get. I am pretty sure most of these sets will be meaningful and will be useless.
In a script a loop is easy, while in the gui you have to keep it simple or use a list coprehension hackishly.

```
 from itertools import combinations
 for s in combinations(onames, 5): cmd.save('-'.join(s)+'.pdb', ' or '.join(s))
```

Obviously, you could alternatively use an enumerate method around the iterator and get an index for the file. But do note f-strings will not work.

```
 for i, s in enumerate(combinations(onames, 5)): cmd.save(str(i)+'.pdb', ' or '.join(s))
```